# Dockerfile: How to run chsh for non root user

Tags: docker

I have the following Dockerfile. The aim is to install zsh and add a non root user and change its shell

```
FROM amazon/aws-cli:latest

RUN yum -y update && yum install shadow-utils.x86_64 zsh util-linux-user -y 

# explanation of above packages
# shadow-utils.x86_64 required to get addgroup / adduser
# util-linux-user required to get chsh
# zsh to install zsh

RUN useradd -m -r -u 1000 -g users simha

WORKDIR /home/simha

USER simha

RUN chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh
```

But I get

```
Changing shell for simha.
Password: chsh: Authentication failure
chsh: changing user attribute failed: Permission denied
The command '/bin/sh -c chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Can anyone help how to change the shell to zsh for non root

Comment: what if move `chsh` command above `useradd`?

Comment: A Docker container runs a single process.  That process isn't typically anything that runs a normal Linux login sequence, and in most cases the shell in `/etc/passwd` will be completely ignored.  Are you trying to replicate a multi-user interactive-login virtual-machine setup in a container?  Using a VM (or, in an AWS context, an EC2 instance) might work better.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default shell for `simha` at user creation by providing `useradd` the `-s /usr/bin/zsh` argument.

Example:

```
FROM amazon/aws-cli:latest

RUN yum -y update && yum install shadow-utils.x86_64 zsh util-linux-user -y

# explanation of above packages
# shadow-utils.x86_64 required to get addgroup / adduser
# util-linux-user required to get chsh
# zsh to install zsh

RUN useradd -m -r -u 1000 -g users simha -s /usr/bin/zsh

WORKDIR /home/simha
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
RUN echo Before: $SHELL
USER simha
RUN echo After: $SHELL
```

I am not sure why `chsh` doesn't work here. Maybe it depends on the configuration of the Docker image.